# Display Subclass of List correctly in Debugger

Tags: c#, list, debugging, display

In my Program I wrote a Subclass of `List` here called `BetterList`.

The debugger shows both as follows:

[image: Pic]

Can I override something so that `BetterList` is displayed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the new class exposes a `Count` property, You can add the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the class to show the property while debugging

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
public class BetterList: List<SomeType> {
    //...

    public int Count { get; }
}
```

For more complex display scenarios review [Using DebuggerTypeProxy Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-debuggertypeproxy-attribute)

> [`DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute) specifies a proxy, or stand-in, for a type and changes the way the type is displayed in debugger windows. When you view a variable that has a proxy, the proxy stands in for the original type in the display. The debugger variable window displays only the public members of the proxy type. Private members are not displayed.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(BetterListDebuggerView))]
public class BetterList: List<SomeType> {
    //...

    public int Count { get; }

    internal class BetterListDebuggerView {
        private BetterList list;
        public BetterListDebuggerView(BetterList list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
        public SomeType[] Items {
            get {
                return list.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, can i use the same to display the listvalues?
Like when you unfold the list you see its members while when you unfold the betterList you only see the RawView of the List

Comment: @JavaJawa there is a [DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute) for more complex customizations.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` for this scenario.

Check [Enhancing Debugging with the Debugger Display Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes) documentation for additional details about it and few similar attributes with richer functionality.